# Change in the rating system of Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

When someone does make a question it is possible for someone to downgrade his question without further details. One **important** change here would be to make the downvote named (the person who performs it would be able to be seen by the according question). 
 Also, before being able to apply the downgrade, he/she should specify why the downgrade is for, so the person who asks the question will be able to correct the mistake and make the forum a better place. What are your ideas?

Comment: My downgrade here is because your request makes up for half of the [status-declined]'s, I reckon.

Comment: My reasons for a required reason to issue a down vote to a question or answer, would always be the following, "I don't find this question/answer helpful" even if I had other reasons.  Forced comment will become a canned comment, and I would never provide additional details, "because of reasons".  I don't find this suggestion to be helpful, I disagree with it, pure meta policy on votes

Answer (score 14):

Such an important change would cause people to not vote as much.

And therefore, bad/low quality questions will stay around for much longer.

Bringing the quality of the whole site down. And driving away people.

---

This has been discussed from the very early days of the site, which a simple search before asking this question would have shown.

Comment: I know about the older questions. Though when someone is stating his mind he/she should have the power of his words. What does it mean ''would cause people not to vote that much''?

Comment: If you know about the older questions, you know there is nothing new about what you are saying - there are no new arguments. Why bring it up _yet again_? As for how this would cause a decrease in voting - your suggestion is to force people to comment - that's more steps - which some people won't proceed with. Comments also have names attached to them, so voting suddenly isn't anonymous - people won't want to self-identify in this way, also because of the possibility of getting revenge down voted.

Comment: @oded but then the revenge-downvoter would have to supply a reason.

Comment: @Mithrandir - that may be the case (depending on implementation), but the other points do stand.

Comment: @Mithrandir Just because somebody is forced to leave a comment does not mean the comment would Explain the reason for the vote, my reasons for a vote, normally come down to the fact the question/answer isn't helpful and normally extremely poorly written or shows a complete lack of research on the subject.  So my reasons for a down vote is normally explained by the current over text... Perhaps some content really is bad, and does not need, an explainations (in other words it really is the content and not the community that's the problem)